# Is "rewirings" a word?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

Is "rewirings" a word? I recently found myself at need for its use and every location I search says it's spelled incorrectly / doesn't exist, yet I'm fairly certain this would be the correct word to express multiples rewires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m thinking that you haven't asked quite the right question here, but I’m trying to figure out a better way to ask it.  The bottom line is that of course it's a word, and to my mind also the right word to use here.

As for something or someone telling you it wasn’t, I have to ask:

- **Did an actual human being tell you it’s not a word, and was this person a lexicographer or linguist?**

Unless the answer to both those questions is *yes*, then you have no reason to believe them.

You’re simply applying basic rules of morphology and derivation here, and any human being who knows the business would vet this application in an instant.

It’s just sub-clued programmers of little learning who don’t know how to write a reasonable computer algorithm writing prescriptively uninspired programs that screws people up.  Don’t trust a computer to have had a professionally educated human behind its algorithm, and therefore do not trust it.

Comment: Ah thanks @tchrist I believe your correct. My intuition was telling me that was the case and its just used so infrequently that it just won't show up when I search for it. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't one of those weird Latin spelling quirks.