# "cactusings" or "cactiing"

Tags: word-choice, latin

I am aware this is a nonsensical / silly question, but [my last question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328228/is-rewirings-a-word)
got me thinking about this. Say you have a hypothetical verb ending in -us. Lets pretend this verb is the word "Cactus".

Some fake examples of our hypothetical -us verb.

> To cactus or not to cactus-that is the question!
>
> I cactus with my friends on weekends.
>
> I just cactused my pants!
>
> Are you going cactusing this weekend?

Now if you tried to make "cactusing" plural how would you go about that?

> Cactiing

or

> Cactusings

What is the proper way to express multiple "cactusings".

Comment: Why not use *caucus*?

Answer (score 3):

Consider how when someone gets *goosed*, if you call that a *goosing*, then if it happened several times, those would be *several goosings* not *several *geesing*.

By analogy, the answer to your question then must be *cactusings* for more than one *cactusing* instance of somebody getting *cactused*.

As Peter Shor rightly points out in comments, the plural of *footing* is not **feeting*. It is *footings*.

Latin noun morphology no more enters the picture here for *cactus, cacti* than does noun English morphology for *goose, geese*.  We don’t do that when we verb nouns.

Comment: And similarly, the plural of *footing* is not *feeting*.